# Yii framework on Nginx - Page doesn't load

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, yii

I am trying to collaborate `Nginx` and `Yii`. I have set `nginx root` directory as the `yii webapp` as - `yiic webapp /usr/share/nginx/app`

In this directory I have some number of default files like yii's `index.php`, `index-test.php` along with the essential folders like `protected`, `themes`, `css` and `images`. Also I have my own files; `phpinfo.php` to print `phpinfo()` and `getAttribute.php` to print some columns from the `mysql` table `history`. I am able to display the phpinfo when I hit `http://localhost/phpinfo.php` but I can't show the output of `getAttribute.php`-

```
#getAttribute.php
<?php
public function attributeLabels() {
return array(
    Yii::t('app','model.history.sfExternalfield')=>array(
            'External Field'=>Yii::t('app','model.history.sfExternalfield'),
            'Delivery Status'=>Yii::t('app','model.history.deliveryStatus'),
    )
);
}
?>
<html>
<body><?php
print_r(attributeLabels()); 
?></body>
</html>
<?php ?>
```

Is there something wrong with this code?

Comment: first thing you can't have the `public` modifier here without having the function within a class. Second, tell me where is this file? in the root folder, along with index.php etc, or within a subfolder?

Comment: @bool.dev, Thanks for replying. I'll remove `public` and check it out. And yes, this file is in the `root` folder, along with the index.php and other default files.

Comment: @bool.dev, I remvoed - `public`. The page loads in the browser but it is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things wrong with the code:

1. As i mentioned in the comment, you can't have the `public` keyword without a class, so you have to remove that first.
2. Secondly since this file is not being accessed through the index.php, but directly, it means that the framework is not yet loaded/initialized. So you don't have access to the `Yii` class yet. To do that you'll have to include the Yii class, somewhat like this:

   ```
   $yii='path/to/framework/yii.php';
   require_once($yii);
   // now Yii is available and you can call Yii::t();
   ```

Comment: my framework folder is at `/Documents/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework`. When I set `$yii` variable to this path, it doesn't work. I get `Server Error` in google-chrome. Should I set `$yii` to `/Documents/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/yiic.php` or some other file?

Comment: Updated `$yii` to the path to yii.php which is `/Documents/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/yii.php` and it seems to work. It gives `Array ( [model.history.sfExternalfield] => Array ( [External Field] => model.history.sfExternalfield [Delivery Status] => model.history.deliveryStatus ) )` in the browser, but not the actual data from `history` model. Thanks anyway man.

Comment: model - "history" created by `model` and `crud` commands from `yiic` prompt works fine in the framework when I hit - `http://localhost/index.php?r=history`. I think, maybe I should have an - `MVC pattern` for my getAttribute.php

Comment: yes you are right, about going for an mvc pattern, is the way. if you tell me what is your actual goal of this file i could probably give you more details.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17541/discussion-between-hussain-tamboli-and-bool-dev)